# Why does this regular expression match group 2 in Golang and Python but not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using a regular expression to repeatedly match the first and second part of a section. It does this fine.

I also want it to optionally capture the last instance of something in the first part which is exactly three digits. I don't need the value of that sub-part. I only need to know it is there. So, I use the first and third group from the match and test if the second group is undefined or not.

The problem I'm having is in JavaScript mode the second group result is always undefined.

See this at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bEVKB4/2).

After seeing it's not working in JavaScript, change to any of the other modes (Golang, Python...) and the first match will provide '123' for the second group. That's what I'd like it to do in JavaScript, but, it doesn't.

**So, why doesn't it do the same in JavaScript? Is there a way I can make a regular expression in JavaScript to produce the desired results?**

Try this out in JavaScript:

```
var regex = /((?:([0-9]{3})|[^,])+?)(?:,([^\.]*))?(?:\.|$)/g
  , string = 'some 123 thing, to test this with. which shows, not working in JS only'

console.log(regex.exec(string))

/* prints this:
[ 'some 123 thing, to test this with.',
  'some 123 thing',
  undefined, // <--------------------- I want this to be '123'
  ' to test with',
  index: 0,
  input: 'the whole string...'
] */

console.log(regex.exec(string))

/* prints this:
[ 'which shows, not working in JS only',
  'which shows',
  undefined, // this one is correct
  ' not working in JS only',
  index: 0,
  input: 'the whole string...'
] */
```

I realize that capturing group only provides the last instance of matching that spot. That's okay because I only want to know it was in there at least once. I'm testing whether the match result's second group exists or is undefined.

This is a simplified example. The basic format is text which is divided by something, in this example, a period (.). Then, the subsection is divided by something else, in this example, a comma. And the first part may have something special in it, in this example, a three digit number.

What I want to do:

```
var match = regex.exec(string)
if (match) {
  var first = match[1]
    , second = match[3]
    , isSpecial = match[2] !== undefined
}
```

Comment: With each iteration of the non-capturing group, the contents inside Group 1 are zeroed/repopulated, this is how ECMAScript regex works. Try re-writing the pattern with a tempered greedy token like [`((?:(?!\d{3})[^,])*(\d{3})?[^,]*)(?:,([^.]*))?(?:\.|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/x9rLYv/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With each iteration of the non-capturing group, the contents inside Group 1 are zeroed/repopulated, this is how ECMAScript regex works. It would work well if your 3-digit chunk appeared right at the `,`, try testing your current regex with [`some 123, to test this with.`](https://regex101.com/r/bEVKB4/3) string.

You need to move the second capturing group outside of the repeated non-capturing group, like:

```
/([^,]*?(?:([0-9]{3})[^,]*)?)(?:,([^.]*))?(?:\.|$)/g
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bEVKB4/4).

Now, the first capturing group pattern matches:

- `[^,]*?` - any 0+ chars other than `,` as few as possible
- `(?:([0-9]{3})[^,]*)?` - one or zero occurrences of:

  - `([0-9]{3})` - Group 1 capturing 3 digits
  - `[^,]*`  - zero or more chars other than `,` as many as possible.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem perfectly. I was able to adapt it into the complicated thing I was doing and it worked great.